# javascript tag character limit in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, highcharts

I am trying to load a fairly large highcharts chart by loading the javascript for the chart with ajax. As in the entire chart is loaded by ajax, not updated by ajax. This works on all charts on firefox(even if it is really slow) and all but the largest charts in chrome.

Any chart that has more than roughly 65000 characters (probably unsigned 16 bit variable but not sure) throws an 'Unexpected end of input error' in chrome. I have had charts just above this limit, then by simply reducing the number of characters, it worked.

The entire ajax response is there so it doesn't appear to be an ajax issue.

Is there some sort of character limit on a javascript tag for chrome? And if there is, does a work around exist?

Comment: Have you looked at the data and see if it is messed up somehow? That error normally means there is a missing ] or something similar.

Comment: While that is what the error usually means, and yes I have checked it, the error always occurs near the same place, character length wise, regardless of what graph I am generating. Like I said, reducing the # of characters by changing variable names to shorter versions fixed the problem on graphs just over the apparent character limit. Also it works with tons of other graphs. The only difference I could find between the working graphs and the broken ones is length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just paginating the chart as to avoid the limit of characters, helps readability anyway.